# How can I render some JSX with onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to render some JSX when a user presses a button, I'm trying to do this via onClick but it is not working, The JSX does not get rendered on the screen. Is there a way to do this? My code is like this:

```
function RandomScreen() {
    async function HandleClick() {
        // make API post request
        .then(function(response) {
            return (<h1>{response.data}</h1>)
        })
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={HandleClick}>Click me</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: Returning jsx from the function would not work, it needs to be part of the return block. Are you trying to show the text above/below the button?

Comment: Below the button, Can I possibly return a whole screen? It would be better if button was not there after the user pressed it. @ksankar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function RandomScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  async function HandleClick() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);

        setData(json);
      });
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={HandleClick}>
      Click me
      {data && <h1>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</h1>}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

store your data in a state for example

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState();


...
.then(function(response) {
    setData(response.data);
 })
```

and in JSX you can handle the display part:

```
{data && <h1>{data}</h1>}
```