# React not rendering jsx in onClick Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am new to learning react and am stuck with this doubt. I have a simple button and on click of that button I want to add some text (or any other html) element. The console log statement is getting executed but the div tag is not getting rednered. This is my following code.

```
function App() {
  const executeMe = () => {
    console.log("executed")
    return(
      <div> Clicked here</div>

    )
  }
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <div className="App">
        Hello world
        <Button onClick={executeMe}> click me</Button>
        
    </div>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I know that I am missing out something which may be very simple. Please help me fix this. Thanks

Comment: you're looking for conditional rendering.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241109/how-can-i-render-some-jsx-with-onclick-event
2.  https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: What changes will I have to do in my code

Answer (score 1):

Your looking at React wrongly, it doesn't work this way. You can do this instead.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);
  const executeMe = () => setClicked(!clicked);
  const onAddLine= () => setLines(lines.concat("New line (Could be unique)"));
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello world
      {/* METHOD A */}
      {!clicked && <button onClick={executeMe }>Click me</button>}
      {clicked && <div>Clicked here</div>}
      <br />
      {/* METHOD B */}
      <button onClick={executeMe}>{clicked ? "Clicked here" : "Click me"}</button>
      <br />
      {/* ADDITIONAL FUN STUFF WITH SEPERATE BUTTON */}
      <button onClick={onAddLine}>Add new line</button>
      <br />
      {lines.map((line, x) => {
        return(
          <div key = {x}>{x+1} : {line}</div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I need to get a new "Clicked me" text below the button everytime  I click the button

Comment: So each time you click it generates a line of text above, so 10 clicks 10 lines ?

Answer (score 0):

You can render that div by using state instead and reset it on the next click.

```js
function App() {

  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);

  const executeMe = () => {
    console.log("executed");
    setShowDiv(!showDiv);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <div className="App">
        Hello world
        <Button onClick={executeMe}> click me</Button>

        {showDiv && <div> Clicked here</div>}  {/* render div once showDiv state is true */}

      </div>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a state value to check when the button has been pressed.
Here is [more information](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) about how to use useState hook.

```js
    function App() {
      const [isButtonPressed, setIsButtonPressed] = useState(false);

      const executeMe = () => {
        console.log("executed");
        setIsButtonPressed(true);
      }

      return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <div className="App">
            Hello world
            <Button onClick={executeMe}> click me</Button>
            {isButtonPressed && <div>Clicked here</div>}
        </div>
        </LocalizationProvider>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it.
First React is just JavaScript, most JS code will work within the component.
But some dev might find it `not so React` which is weird for me :)

So here are the two examples that you might try:

```js
function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([])

  const handleAddLine = () => {
    const lists = document.getElementById('lists')
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    li.textContent = 'hey'
    lists.append(li)
  }

  const handleAddLineReactish = () => {
    setList(prevList => {
      return prevList.concat(<li>hey</li>)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={handleAddLine}>Add</button>
      <ul id='lists'></ul>
      <button onClick={handleAddLineReactish}>Add Reactish</button>
      <ul>
        {list.length > 0 && list.map((l, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={i}>{l}</li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

sandbox URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-sun-7f4epn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

For something like this we use a react hook called "useState".
In "useState" we store a something and on the basis of that we do stuff like to show, hide and more.

---

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exTpR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can write that html code in another component and import it into the current file you can make useState to check the value is 'visible' with type 'true/false' to check the state when the button is click.

code example

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
  const executeMe = () => {
    console.log("executed")
    setShowText(true);
  }
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <div className="App">
        Hello world
        <Button onClick={executeMe}> click me</Button>
        {showText ? <Text /> : null}
        
    </div>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
const Text = () => <div>You clicked the button!</div>;
export default App;
```

Comment: {showText && <Text />} would be better, no need for null

Comment: Can we do the same without using another component ?  I need to get a new line of text everytime I click the button, Then the first time the state gets changed to true,,, How to reset it the next time ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).